# What did i wrong in my image turn algoritm?

Tags: c++, image

I just want to turn image #1 and write it in memory #2 (**#1 Body #2 TurnBody**) (*rotation around the center of the image*)

**KI** and **KJ** its just **(i-radius)** and **(j-radius)** for usage. **SIN** and **COS** its just sin and cos of turn angle.

**radius - just half of image side (my image is square)**

6.28 = pi*2

example i need to turn

[image: input]

example i have:
[image: output]

(i turn not all image, just a small square in center and add it to big screen image)

TurnAngle - just my global value (shows what angle the image is now rotated)

```
void Turn(double angle, int radius, COLORREF* Body, COLORREF* TurnBody)
        {        
            if (abs(TurnAngle += angle) > 6.28)
            {
                TurnAngle = 0;
            }
            int i, ki, j, kj;
            const double SIN = sin(TurnAngle), COS = cos(TurnAngle);

            for (i = 0, ki = -radius; i < 2 * radius; i++, ki++)
            {
                for (j = 0, kj = -radius; j < 2 * radius; j++, kj++)
                { 
                    if (Body[i * 2 * radius + j]) // if Pixel not black
                    { 
                        TurnBody[static_cast<int>(kj * COS - ki * SIN + radius + (ki * COS + kj * SIN + radius) * 2 * radius)] = Body[i * 2 * radius + j];
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

this work, smth was wrong with ( ) or double values i rly dont know... Thank you guys

```
this->TurnBody[(int)(kj * COS - ki * SIN) + this->radius + ((int)(ki * COS + kj * SIN) + this->radius) * 2 * this->radius] = this->Body[i * 2 * this->radius + j];
```

Comment: I have a squard image with many black pixels aroung center small image, i cant out of range, srsly

Answer (score 1):

I think this is wrong:

```cpp
TurnBody[static_cast<int>(kj * COS - ki * SIN + radius + (ki * COS + kj * SIN + radius) * 2 * radius)] = Body[i * 2 * radius + j];
```

I think it should be more like this:

```cpp
TurnBody[(int)(kj * COS) + radius + ((int)(kj * SIN) + radius) * 2*radius] = Body[i * 2 * radius + j];
```

Comment: No, just try to calculate it. It will be always just a line.

Comment: But i try to use (int) 2 times instead static_cast<int> 1 time and MY ALGORITM START WORK OMG

Comment: Thank you but i think i dont need upvote your answer bcs it was wrong

Comment: this->TurnBody[(int)(kj * COS - ki * SIN) + this->radius + ((int)(ki * COS + kj * SIN) + this->radius) * 2 * this->radius] = this->Body[i * 2 * this->radius + j]; this work now